# Wordpress $wpdb get posts from category and sort by custom meta

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I have a custom post type of 'events' which has a meta key 'event_date'

Im using the following to retrieve those posts and arrange them by 'event_date'

```
        global $wpdb;
        $today = date('Y/m/d', strtotime("now"));
        $events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
                                            posts.id, posts.post_title, meta.meta_value 
                                        FROM 
                                            {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as meta
                                        LEFT JOIN 
                                            {$wpdb->prefix}posts as posts 
                                        ON 
                                            (meta.post_id = posts.id) 
                                        WHERE
                                            (meta.meta_key = 'event_date' 
                                        AND
                                            meta.meta_value >= '{$today}'
                                        AND
                                            posts.post_status='publish' and posts.post_date < NOW())
                                        ORDER BY 
                                            meta.meta_value
                                    ");
```

The above works fine however i would like to show 'events' from only certain categories (say category id '5'). How can i modify the query to achive this?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `wp query` it have the paramaters your asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `NOW()` in select queries since `NOW()` returns the current date and time to the split second. In other words: This query will never land in the cache.

And you can use the WP_Query with filter of `posts_where` eg:

```
function filter_event_where( $where = '' ) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d'); 
    $where .= " AND posts.post_date < '".$date."'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_event_where' );
$today = date('Y/m/d', strtotime("now"));
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'event_date', //used for order
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', //used for order
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
    ));
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_event_where' );
```

Comment: This is brilliant, helped loads. Thankyou :)